# manipulate state of a sibling component

Tags: react-native

```
component A

render(){
    <View>
        {this.renderB()}
        {this.renderC()}
    </View>
}

component B

super(props){
    this.state={text: (this.props.text) ? this.props.text : '' }
}
render(){
}

component C

super(props){
}
render(){
    <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={
     ...here I want to modify text state of component B
   }></TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
}
```

Is it possible to modify state of sibling like so? or should I move `text` properties here to component A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to share state between components, move that state up to their common parent and push them down through props.

Here's the gist of what I'm getting at. Obviously, you'd need to pass up actual values.

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: '',
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <ComponentB text={this.state.text}>
        <ComponentC onPress={(value) => this.setState({text: value})}>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class ComponentB extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
    )
  }
}

class ComponentC extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onPress} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```